# Unable to add external JDBC jar file to Spring Boot, despite adding it to application.properties

Tags: java, spring-boot, jdbc

I tried following the instructions mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24086178/1243462) to add a driver for the SAP HANA database. The driver is available as a jar file, and had been added to the pom.xml:

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sap.db.jdbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>ngdbc</artifactId>
        <version>1.96.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

My application properties was as follows:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sap://<YOUR SAP HANA IP>:host
spring.datasource.username=sap_hana_user
spring.datasource.password=sap_hana_password
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.sap.db.jdbc.Driver
```

However, that didn't work, and I was still getting the error message:

`Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE`.

What **did** work, was adding the Datasource programmatically, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28822145/1243462), and removing the `application.resources` file. So, finally, my `Application.java` looks like:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer
{
    @Bean
    @Primary
    public DataSource dataSource()
    {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().username("user_name_sap_hana").password("password_sap_hana").url("jdbc:sap://<YOUR SAP HANA IP>:port").driverClassName("com.sap.db.jdbc.Driver").build();//https://stackoverflow.com/a/28822145/1243462 ; https://stackoverflow.com/a/1336965/1243462
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application)
    {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Could someone please explain what I did wrong? The first method did not mention having to do anything besides enter these details in `application.resources`.

Comment: Suppose 'spring.datasource.driver-class-name' should be in 'application.properties'

Comment: Whoops, sorry. That was a typo in copy-pasting the code from Eclipse to my browser. Fixed it. But, even including the driver tag didn't work.

Comment: `spring.datasource.driver-class-name:com.sap.db.jdbc.Driver` looks wrong, should be -> `spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.sap.db.jdbc.Driver`

Comment: I just cannot catch a break :-/ . Okay, I edited the post with the copy paste from the commit right before I made the final `Application.java` class, with the Datasource.